# MySQL won't start with innodb_log_file_size set

Tags: mysql, linux, innodb, confluence

I'm running a MySQL 5.5.57 on a Debian 3.16.43-2 inside of a VMware machine.

I need to set innodb_log_file_size >= 256MB but with this setting in my.cnf MySQL don't start anymore.

I've tried to delete the ib_logfile0 + 1 files before starting like stated from some other posts but i doesn't help.

What can i do next?
Best Mario

Comment: What's in the error log file?

Comment: Why do you think you need a bigger size?  256MB is big enough for most sites.

Comment: @RickJames In my case nothing that can lead to an explanation ... :/

Comment: @Pathros - Use `GLOBAL STATUS` to compute `Uptime / 60 * innodb_log_file_size / Innodb_os_log_written` -- If it is much _less_ than 60 (minutes), then it might help to increase log_file_size.  See this for how to change:  https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/4103/1876

Comment: To shed some light into Ricks question: Confluence wants this.